# Register an Assembly in web applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, ado.net, dll

I have a System.Web.DataVisualization.dll present in my bin folder.
I have copy and pat the following register tag in my page from interner and the .dll is working fine.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Now my question is
How to find or determine the version and Namespace for an Assembly from System.Web.DataVisualization.dll?
How I can determine the version for this System.Web.DataVisualization.dll?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use reflection:

```
  Assembly[] myAssemblies = Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies();

  Assembly myAssembly = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < myAssemblies.Length; i++)
  {
     if(String.Compare(myAssemblies[i].GetName().Name, 
                       "System.Web.DataVisualization") == 0)
     {
        myAssembly = myAssemblies[i];
        break;
     }
  }
  var myVersion  = myAssembly.GetName().Version;

  var namespaces = myAssembly.GetTypes()
                     .Select(t => t.Namespace)
                     .Distinct();
```